# FASTER WAY TO COPY DATA TO EXCEL?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, excel-2007

Excuse-me if the question is inappropriate , but is the fowlloing code ***which is to copy a table from a dataset into an Excel sheet*** considered dummy or a Trivial Solution for the problem ?

And if it was so ,how about copying a complete Row does it take the same time or it will be faster.

```
 Private Sub btnExportoEcel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExportEcel.Click
    Dim excelObj As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim WBk As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim sht As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim pathOfxl As String
    diagSave.ShowDialog()
    pathOfxl = diagSave.FileName



    excelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    WBk = excelObj.Workbooks.Add
    sht = WBk.ActiveSheet
    sht.Activate()
    With sht.Range("A1", "F1")
        .Font.Bold = True

        .Borders.Weight = 2
        .ColumnWidth = 30

    End With
    sht.Cells(1, 1).value = "First Name"
    sht.Cells(1, 2).value = "Last Name"
    sht.Cells(1, 3).value = "Phone Number"
    sht.Cells(1, 4).value = "Mobile Number"
    sht.Cells(1, 5).value = "Email Address"
    'Below is a user control which i created to show Visual Progressing         
     myProgressBar = New Progress'user control class
    myProgressBar.pbMin = 0
    myProgressBar.pbMax = contactView.Rows.Count
    myProgressBar.setTitle = "Copy to Excel"
    myProgressBar.Show()


       ' Here it starts copying CELLS one by one 
       For datarw = 1 To contactView.Rows.Count
         myProgressBar.increasePbarValue()
        For dataclm = 0 To 4
            sht.Cells(datarw + 1, dataclm + 1).value =    dataSet.Tables("Contact").Rows(datarw - 1).Item(dataclm + 1)
         Next

     Next


     WBk.SaveAs(pathOfxl)
     WBk.Saved = True
     WBk.Close()



     excelObj.Quit()

    myProgressBar.Dispose()

    myProgressBar = Nothing
    excelObj = Nothing
    WBk = Nothing
    sht = Nothing
    pathOfxl = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Does this belong on [Code Review - Excel](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) ? Working code looking for improvements have a home there.

Comment: Yes, transferring a whole row at a time is faster than individual cells. So is removing the  progress bar.

Comment: Well, that would be **another question**. Please read  [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625) and make a decision on what you want to ask and [ask]. Soliciting opinions is a reason to Vote-to-Close.